# How to save images taken from Webcam to a specific location

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

```
>   if key == ord('s'):
>         cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("\ima", x+'.jpg'), img=frame)
>         webcam.release()
>         cv2.waitKey(1650)
>         cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

ima is the folder i want to save the images at. When i run the above code i am not getting any error, but the image is not saving at all.

Comment: Looks like there is a parentheses error change like that cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("\ima",filename=x+'.jpg'), img=frame)

Comment: After changing the code a little i am getting any error but the image is the saving in the ima folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a full path. You can use os.getcwd() if the save location is inside your current working directory or you can manually type it ie: "C:\ima"

```
import os
os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"ima","newfile.jpg")
```